# Understanding better conditional expectation : example with tossing coin.

Tags: probability, expected-value

We toss a fair coin three times. So the probability space is given by $(\Omega ^3, \mathcal F^{\otimes 3},\mathbb P^{\otimes 3})$ where $\Omega =\{H,T\}$, $\mathcal F=2^\Omega $ and $\mathbb P\{\omega \}=1/2$.

Let the $\sigma -$algebra
$$\mathcal F_1=\sigma \{A_1,A_2\},$$
where $A_1=\{(H,T,T),(H,T,H),(H,H,T),(H,H,H)\}$ and $A_2=\{(T,T,T),(T,T,H),(T,H,T),(T,H,H)\}$,

Let $X:\Omega ^3\to \mathbb R^3$ defined by $X=(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ where $X_i:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ are defined by $X_i=\boldsymbol 1_{\{H\}}$.

I know $$\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal F_1](\omega _1,\omega _2,\omega _3)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\mathbb P(A_1)}\int_{A_1}Xd\mathbb P^{\otimes 3}&\omega _1=H\\
\frac{1}{\mathbb P(A_2)}\int_{A_2}Xd\mathbb P^{\otimes 3}&\omega _1=T,
\end{cases}$$
but I don't know how to compute those quantity. I think $\mathbb P(A_i)=\frac{1}{2}$, but I'm not sure how to compute $\int_{A_1}X d\mathbb P^{\otimes 3}$. Is it just $$\mathbb P\{X_1=1, X_2=0, X_3=0\}+\mathbb P\{X_1=1,X_2=1,X_3=0\}+\mathbb P\{X_1=1, X_2=0,X_3=1\}+\mathbb P\{X_1=1,X_2=1,X_3=1\} \ \ ?$$
If yes, by independence of $X_i$ I find $4\cdot \frac{1}{8}$ and thus $$\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal F_1]=2\cdot \frac{1}{2}=1$$ that look quite strange for me. It looks quite complicated for such an "easy" problem.

Comment: What is the point of this? It just looks like an egregious redundancy in notation. What are the problems that this helps you solve?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee: Sorry, it's the definitions of my course... I just need to compute $\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal F_1]$. Thank you.

Comment: Please define $X$ and the $X_i$s.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee On the contrary, looking at extremely simple examples helps check whether the idea of the definitions involved got through... or not.

Comment: From a previous version: "Let $X:\Omega ^3\to \mathbb R^3$ given by $X_i:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ given by $X_i=\boldsymbol 1_{\{H\}}$. Consider $X:\Omega ^3\to \mathbb R^3$ given by $X=(X_1,X_2,X_3)$. I would like to compute $\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal F_1].$" Thus, the answer is $$E(X\mid \mathcal F_1)=(X_1,E(X_2),E(X_3))=(X_1,\tfrac12,\tfrac12)$$

Comment: @Did: thank you, I didn't see that I erased this part. I add it again. So for example $$\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal F_1](H,\omega _1,\omega _2)=\frac{1}{\mathbb P(A_1)}\left(\int _{A_1}H d\mathbb P^{\otimes 3},\int _{A_1}X_2d\mathbb P^{\otimes 3},\int _{A_1}X_3d\mathbb P^{\otimes 3}, \right) \ \ ?$$

And for example $$\int_{A_1}X_2d\mathbb P^{\otimes 3}=\sum_{i=0}^1 i\mathbb P\{X_1=1, X_2=i,X_3=1\}+\sum_{i=0}^1 i\mathbb P\{X_1=1,X_2=i,X_3=0\}$$ ?

Comment: Also, since $\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal F_1]\neq X$ I can say that it's not a martingale right ? @Did

Comment: Sorry but none of your two comments is making any sense (and one can wonder whether you simply read the formula in mine). For exaple, for every $\omega_2$ and $\omega_3$ in $\{H,T\}$, $$E(X\mid\mathcal F_1)(H,\omega_2,\omega_3)=(1,\tfrac12,\tfrac12)$$ and $$E(X\mid\mathcal F_1)(T,\omega_2,\omega_3)=(0,\tfrac12,\tfrac12)$$

Comment: By the way, your definition of $X_i$ is absurd, these are functions defined on $\Omega^3$, not on $\Omega$, thus, $$X_i(\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3)=\mathbf 1_{\omega_i=H}$$ Please compare with what you write.

Comment: @Did : Good point, indeed. So is $\int_{A_1}X_2\mathbb P^{\otimes 3}$ is just $\mathbb P^{\otimes 3}\{X_2=1\}=\frac{1}{2}$ ?

Comment: ??? $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: @Did: Sorry, I wanted to say $\int_{A_1}X_2d\mathbb P^{\otimes 3}=\mathbb P^{\otimes 3}\{X_2=1\}=\frac{1}{2}$. Every thing is well defined no ? $X_2:\Omega ^3\to \mathbb R$, $\mathbb P^{\otimes 3}$ is a measure on $\Omega ^3$... what wouldn't be correct ? (thank you)

Comment: $\frac14$, not $\frac12$.

Comment: @Did: Yes, thank you very much :) (indeed, $\mathbb P\{\omega \in A_1\mid X_2=1\}=1/4$.

Comment: $\frac12$, not $\frac14$. (Sorry but what are you doing?)

Comment: @Did: Yes indeed, so why did you tell me that $\int_{A_1}X_2d\mathbb P^{\otimes 3}=\mathbb P\{\omega \in A_1\mid X_2=1\}=\frac{1}{4}$ (may be I misunderstanding something ?).

Comment: **I did not say that**. Note that $\int_{A_1}X_2dP^{\otimes3}$ is neither equal to $ P^{\otimes3}(A_1\mid X_2=1)$ nor to $P^{\otimes3}(X_2=1)$. That you keep confusing these quantities (and other ones) and that you seem to be unable to read what others are writing, are two reasons (amongst others) which makes that discussing your question with you is improductive.

Comment: @did: I'm sorry to make you angry... I thought $\frac{1}{\mathbb P(A_1)}\int_{A_1}X_2d\mathbb P^{\otimes 3}=\mathbb E[X_2\mid A_1]$ and since $X_2\in\{0,1\}$ I thought that was $\mathbb P\{A_1\mid X_2=1\}/\mathbb P(A_1)$... but it doesn't look true...

Comment: @Did: Thank you anyways :)